# Why would an induction cooker periodically click when idle?

Tags: power, switches, switching, induction

A typical induction cooker has output power adjustment which is usually implemented in two fashions. Higher power settings are "continuous" - the cooker outputs say 1200 watts all the time it is switched on. Lower power settings are "switching" - the cooker would claim its power is 300 watts but it actually cycles between say 800 watts and no power. The second mode can be confirmed when boiling previously hot water at lower power settings - when the cooker inductor is actually on the water starts boiling and when it's off the water suspends boiling and water cycles between boiling and not boiling all the time.

So there're several cookers of different models and they all show the same behavior. When a lower power setting is selected the cooker cycles between two phases. In "on" phase the cooker produces only fan noise and causes water to boil. In "off" phase the cooker produces fan noise and also periodical clicking sounds when are similar to some relay switching or something like that and in this phase water does not boil. The clicks sound all the same no matter which cookware is used so it's likely not from magnetic fields interacting with the cookware but from the cooker electronics. Clicking sound rate is roughly one click per second during each "off" phase and no clicking sound occurs during the "on" phase.

I guess this is a well known way to implement the cycling between "on" and "off" phases.

Why would those clicking sounds be produced when the cooker is in "off" phase? What would cause them?

Comment: Ah, the answer is hidden in this 50 minutes YouTube video: #240 Induction Cooker / Induction Heater Functional & Circuit Description, Repair Troubleshooting
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZ8qGGKURRA. Happy watching.

Comment: Or read the friendly datasheet (1) TM1628: Induction cooker TM1628 SM1628C power management chip--HDSDZ New IC HT1628 - US$0.23
https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/induction-cooker-TM1628-SM1628C-power-management_60289740669.html?spm=a2700.7724857.normal_offer.d_title.7552c6fdIzLG1f. (2) TM1628 LED Driver -Titan
http://aitendo3.sakura.ne.jp/aitendo_data/product_img/ic/LED-driver/TM1628english.pdf. Happy datasheet reading.Cheers.

Comment: Does it stop clicking when you lift up the pan away from the hob? You used to be really good at accepting answers. Have you got a little bored with that process recently (last couple of years)?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, if the pan is taken away it just shuts off and shows a "no pan" error message.

Comment: Well, the clicking is likely to be a short burst of induction that tests whether the pan is still present.

Comment: @Andyaka How would those clicking sounds be generated?

Comment: Maybe a relay or maybe the sudden inrush current into the hob or maybe a physical reaction of the pan on the hob produces a mechanical noise. Is it the same sound with different pan sizes? Anyway, this is off-topic now because questions about consumer goods require a tear-down of the schematics and much more detail.

Comment: @tlfong01 I watched the video and it explains how the cooker works quite well but I don't get where the clicking sound comes from.

Comment: @sharptooth, Ah, I have been using a couple of induction cookers in the last 10 years.  I don't hear any clicking sound, but I do notice that the heating is not continuous, but in sort of low very frequency "waves". You might like to give me the link of your cooker, so that we might compare and contrast the datasheets.

Comment: @sharptooth, I am terribly sorry that I gave you the fake fact that all my induction cookers don't click. Actually I don't have sensitive enough ears to hear the very soft clicks. I googled and found that induction cooker clicks are normal, and it is likely that ***ALL induction cookers tick. Though I googled but don't find useful answers. This is one of the best: (1) How Much Noise does an Induction Cooktop Make? - Sasha
https://inductionguide.com/induction-cooktop-noise/. Cheers.